# Laravel not consuming Pusher events

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-echo, pusher-js

This has been a long standing problem for a while now and before I start here's what I've tried and where I've looked for a solution.

**A Few Things I've Tried**

I've made sure that my cluster was correct for the application that I'm using:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/pusher-is-not-receiving-my-message?page=1
My cluster is `eu`

I've tried all variation of namespaces:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/echo-broadcast-event-listener-not-being-triggered
`.App.Events.DefaultPusherEvent`, `App\Events\DefaultPusherEvent`, `.DefaultPusherEvent` etc...

**My Scenario**

So I'm trying to get to grips with real-time updates using Laravel and Pusher so eventually I can implement real-time notifications + whatever else we need in the future.

I got as far as being able to broadcast to my pusher application following the Laravel documentation.

[image: Its Working...]

So that's all fine no issues there, the only issue I have is actually trying to consume this event using Laravel's echo and even Pusher's vanilla code.

I have had this problem before and my solution was to not use private channels (as they didn't work at all for me). But now I need the functionality.

**Progress**

Before posting this question I re-made a fresh installation of Laravel and followed it through again, but the outcome was the same. I even made a login system to make sure it wasn't because my users wasn't because my users weren't logged into the application.

```
ListenForPusherEvents(){
    Echo.private(`datalev`)
        .listen('DefaultPusherEvent', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
            console.log('Something');
        });
}
```

Also I have NO console errors as I've already authenticated the user using pushers `'broadcasting/auth'` directory

This is the code that authenticates the user for the private channel.

```
public function PusherAuthentication(Request $request)
{
    $pusher = new Pusher(env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'), env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'), env('PUSHER_APP_ID'), ['cluster' => 'eu']);
    $pusher->socket_auth($request->input('channel_name'), $request->input('socket_id'));
}
```

Comment: Your Echo code to attach the listener is in a function, how/when is this function called? Is it on a dom ready event? Are you positive `ListenForPusherEvents()` is being called at some point?

Does your code function fully when not using a private channel? IE just replacing the echo listener with one which listens on a public channel, does this work?

Just throwing out ideas because I've had this working.

Comment: @Joe Im positive, its a function because its within vuejs, i can console.log before the echo code and the log shows. I've even moved it outside my vue.js code and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you seeing any ajax request to your laravel to authorize the request?
I set my authorizer manually because I needed to make sure that the CSRF was also picked up and sent a long...

Comment: @DavidHeremans Ill check that out now, thanks for the tip

Comment: @DavidHeremans Yeah im getting a 200 response from the ajax request to auth on the private channel. But do i still need to send a CSRF token? i dont believe ive seen anything to do with it in the docs. If you could post an Example that would be great or something of the sort

Comment: If you're getting the 200, it's fine; you didn't run into the csrf. middleware.  What's the content of the reply?  You should get a json object back with an auth property.  That property is used by Echo to go to pusher and authenticate your subscription request.

Comment: @DavidHeremans ah my response is completely empty, i can finally see some hope in this lol...

Comment: @DavidHeremans aaay i got it, literally the smallest but largest error ive ever had, i didnt echo the key, i just set it in PHP

Comment: Yes.  The workflow is as follows:
1 your client wants to subscribe, and asks laravel if it's okay (the /broadcasting/auth ajax call)
2 your laravel confirms it's okay and informs pusher; you're getting a unique auth key that is sent back to your client through ajax
3 your javascript can then subscribe to the pusher channel using that auth key it received from your laravel, and which is known as a valid key by pusher, so pusher will accept it.

Comment: Brilliant.  Glad I could help.

Comment: @DavidHeremans Put that as the answer whenever you want / if you want and ill accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your broadcasting/auth route correctly returns a JSON object with the auth key. This is used by Pusher to authenticate your subscription to the channel.

The process is as follows:

1. your client wants to subscribe, and asks Laravel if it's okay (the /broadcasting/auth AJAX call)
2. your Laravel confirms it's okay and informs pusher; you're getting a unique auth key that is sent back to your client through AJAX
3. your JavaScript can then subscribe to the Pusher channel using that auth key it received from your Laravel, and which is known as a valid key by Pusher, so Pusher will accept it.